# Google Apps Script PropertiesService access collision

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, thread-safety, collision

I need to access the script properties safely from multiple calls to the script. By using my own method of logging, I can see that the two calls are within milliseconds of each other (2 ms to be exact).

Is there any way at all to ensure that the data written by the first call will be seen by the second? At the moment, the second call checks to see if there's already data in the script properties, but doesn't see what the first call sets because they are too close apart.

Comment: Perhaps [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/lock-service) is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. Turns out it had little to do with collision using the PropertiesService. The callback where the lock is obtained never actually reached the unlocking stage.

For the longest time, I thought it was because a new lock overwrote the current lock's data and caused the unlocking to fail, but it was actually the callback that obtained the lock throwing an exception before it could unlock the lock. I just wrapped its content in a try-catch block and put the unlock call inside the `finally` block.

I really should have figured it out sooner.

Edit: I should specify that the "lock" that I am talking about is not the LockService's lock. It is my own implementation that uses a tag identifier instead of the whole script.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage access to shared resource by using Lock Service. It looks similar to using synchronized blocks of code in Java.

```
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  lock.waitLock(30000);
  var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  properties.setProperty("key", value);            
  lock.releaseLock();
```

I wasn't able to test this - it would be interesting to know if it works for your use case. More on Lock Service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock/

Comment: I was using Lock Service before, but it locks the whole script when I only wanted to lock when certain parameters are met. I can't use script or user lock because I have to be able to call the script from multiple locations (in this case, Google Spreadsheets) through my own privileged Google account. I'm trying to create my own tagged lock system where a lock can be acquired on the basis of tags instead. However, I was not using it in conjunction with my custom lock before, so I could try that.

Comment: I have successfully resolved my issue. It turned out to be unrelated to access collision. I'm sure Google already has that taken care of on their end, anyway.